# Laravel session problems - randomly logged as different user - after deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, session, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My problem is that sometimes when I do a new code deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I already have active session (am logged as myself), then when I refresh the page, I'm logged in as someone else. I use database sessions. This doesn't happen too often - or at least I'm not aware of it but can't figure this out. I'm using standard Laravel login functionality. I'm trying to find at least a start point how/where to start investigating. It has to do something with the deployments to Elastic Beanstalk because that's when this sometimes happen. I would have imagined that using database session shouldn't be affected by code changes on EB. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a caching layer between your application and the browser that might be caching one of the session-related headers?

Comment: All of your servers are accessing the *same* database connection, correct?

Comment: @TravisBritz good thinking! We have AWS CloudFront enabled. I will try to investigate. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @pdolinaj Ever figure this out? Running into a similar problem, also layered behind CloudFront